# Returns 1st row

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am trying to get data of user when he/she logs in. here is the query

```
$sql = "Select * from user LEFT JOIN user_bank ON user_bank.userID=? LEFT  JOIN user_image ON user.id=? AND user_image.userID=? LEFT  JOIN user_location on user_location.userID=?";

$query = $this -> db -> query($sql, array($sessionID, $sessionID, $sessionID, $sessionID));
return $query -> row();
```

Now the id here is 2 and when i turn on the query profile it show query with id 2 but returns the record of first row instead of second why?

Comment: Try return $query ->result(); or return $query -> result_array(); then var dump the results.

Comment: i did it shows all records

Answer (score 0):

If you need  a specific order use order by

```
$sql = "Select * 
        from user 
        LEFT JOIN user_bank ON user_bank.userID=? 
        LEFT  JOIN user_image ON user.id=? AND user_image.userID=? 
        LEFT  JOIN user_location on user_location.userID=?
        ORDER BY your_table.your_column";
```

and if you need  only the firts rows use limit

```
$sql = "Select * 
        from user 
        LEFT JOIN user_bank ON user_bank.userID=? 
        LEFT  JOIN user_image ON user.id=? AND user_image.userID=? 
        LEFT  JOIN user_location on user_location.userID=?
        ORDER BY your_table.your_column
        LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a where clause for "User" table. It returns all user records, and for all records, it joins the data from detail tables for Id 2. Use "where Id = 2" at the end.

Comment: No problem, bro. You could do me a favor by accepting as answer if it solves your problem?